# how to Fix the Div position always below the other upper div?

Tags: css, html, iframe, vertical-alignment

i have one div and on below of that div am showing one div with the iframe which loads the html page in same page dynamicaly..but what happens is the div with an iframe overlay the upper division as the iframe containg html haev long height..so can any one please tell me how i can put the div which contains iframe below the upper div tag regardless of which content loaded in the iframe.and also i want to make it look same in chrome as well as mozila..

following is my structure...

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" id="media_select">
            <label
                style="float: left; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 22px">  Media  
            </label><select style="width:125px" name="mediatype" id="mediatype"
                data-placeholder="- Select Ad Type -" class="chzn-select"
                tabindex="4">
                <option value="0">Select All</option>
                <%
                    List<mediatype> media_typelist = mediatypeLocalServiceUtil
                            .getAllMediaType();
                    for (mediatype media_typelistitem : media_typelist) {
                %>
                <option value=<%=media_typelistitem.getPrimaryKey()%>><%=media_typelistitem.getMedianame()%></option>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="span3">


        </div>
```

//This is the div which i want to fixed just below the upper division

```
<div class="bordercolor" id="mydiv" style="display: none; text-align: center">

    <IFRAME SRC="" id="reportpreview"  style="text-align: center;"
        marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="sizeFrame();"></iframe>

</div>
```

height of iframe assigned dynmaiclly within following script:-

```
function sizeFrame() {
    var F = document.getElementById('reportpreview');
    if(F.contentDocument) {
    F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+30; //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and Chrome
    } else {



    F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+30; //IE6, IE7 and Chrome

    }

    }
```

///css for report preview id //an Iframe

```
   #reportpreview {
        float:center;
        margin-top:10%;
        margin-bottom:10%;
        zoom: 1.2;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        -moz-transform-origin: 2 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 2 0;
        width: 720px;
        min-height: 37px;



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   #reportpreview {
    clear:left;
    float:center;
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    zoom: 1.2;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 2 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 2 0;
    width: 720px;
    min-height: 37px;
    }
```

add `clear:left` to iframe div

Comment: its just moving up everytime i load same iframe.first time its showing good//but when i load same thing then its move to upper side.this happens only in chrome

Comment: then you have to add clear property to upper div also i.e. `clear:right` its for upper div

Comment: try `clear:both` for upper div... i m not sure it will work but may be